# Ember Acceptance testing: check that button isEnabled

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, acceptance-testing

I'm new to ember in general and trying to check (in my Acceptance test), whether a submit button is enabled after entering a valid email. I tried:

```
test('Typing email enables button', function(assert){
  visit('/');
  var theBtn = find('.btn-primary');
  fillIn('.ember-text-field', 'user@userfakemail.com');
  andThen(function(){ 
    assert.equal(theBtn.isEnabled(), true);
  });
});
```

But this doesn't work. And in the guides I could not find what methods were possible with `find()`.

Comment: As far as `find()` goes, it returns a jQuery object, so anything that you can do with that should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the button is disabled by looking at the `disabled` property using the `prop()` method. You can check if the button is enabled like this:

`assert.equal(theBtn.prop('disabled'), false);`

Take a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ff9b5779aebab5f1064a212d1467e22e?openFiles=tests.acceptance.my-acceptance-test.js%2C)